# Create a Lightsail instance and install the CodeDeploy agent

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-code-deploy, amazon-lightsail

While following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-codedeploy-and-aws-codepipeline-to-deploy-applications-to-amazon-lightsail/), I created the instance with the desired script. Yet, when I ssh in and run

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

I'm getting the error

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status codedeploy-agent.service
>
> Unit codedeploy-agent.service could not be found.

What can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I created the instance using Amazon Linux 2, ssh in and run

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

then would get the error

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status codedeploy-agent.service
>
> Unit codedeploy-agent.service could not be found.

In order to fix it, created a new instance but this time made sure to be using Amazon Linux (as opposed to Amazon Linux 2).

[image: Amazon Lightsail Linux instance with codedeploy script]

Now, when running

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

I get the following result

> The AWS CodeDeploy agent is running as PID 2780

[image: The AWS CodeDeploy agent is running as PID 2780]

P.S. - if you still want to use Amazon Linux 2 instead, consider reading [this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64170459/5675325).