# Setup CodePipeline - Deploy step has a status of failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-code-deploy, amazon-lightsail

When setting up CodeDeploy following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-codedeploy-and-aws-codepipeline-to-deploy-applications-to-amazon-lightsail/), under the last step of Setup CodePipeline

[image: Deploy step has a status of failed]

If I click in Details under Failed

[image: Action execution failed]

If I click in Link to execution details

> The deployment failed because no instances were found for your
> deployment group. Check your deployment group settings to make sure
> the tags for your Amazon EC2 instances or Auto Scaling groups
> correctly identify the instances you want to deploy to, and then try
> again.

[image: Link to execution details]

This was most likely due to a problem in locations - sometimes it was used N. Virginia and other times London.

- IAM - does not require region selection.
- S3 - does not require region selection.
- LightSail instance - London, Zone A (eu-west-2a)
- CodeDeploy application - N. Virginia (us-east-1)
- CodeDeploy pipeline - London, Zone A (eu-west-2a)

So, I went to CodeDeploy, deleted the application in N. Virginia and created one with its deployment group in London. Then, created a new pipeline there in London.

The deployment failed this time too but with a different reason

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances
> failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for
> deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are
> experiencing problems.

[image: deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment]

In order to fix that, I've deleted both pipelines and created a new one. Since I had to change the role, I used `AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-eu-west-2-CodeDeployLightsailDemoPipeline` but this got me into troubles in the moment of Creating the pipeline

> Could not create role
> AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-eu-west-2-CodeDeployLightsailDemoPipeline

[image: Could not create role]

So, I changed it to `AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-eu-west-2-CodeDeployLightsailDemoP`. Then, this got me into another problem

> A policy called
> AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-eu-west-2-CodeDeployLightsailDemoPipeline
> already exists. Duplicate names are not allowed.

[image: Duplicate names are not allowed]

So, I went back and changed the Pipeline name to `CodeDeployLightsailDemoPi` and the Role name to `AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-eu-west-2-CodeDeployLightsailDemoPi`.

This got me into the same

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances
> failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for
> deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are
> experiencing problems.

I decided to wait 30 minutes and create a new pipeline giving it the name `CodeDeployLightsailPipeline` and the role name `AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-eu-west-2-CodeDeployLightsailPipelin` but the same problem happened.

This is what the information present in Deployment ID > View events

[image: View Events]

According to [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin), I should have found the [appspec.yml](https://github.com/tiago-peres/CodeDeployGitHubDemo/blob/master/appspec.yml)

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /index.html
    destination: /var/www/html/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

In it, it mentions `destination: /var/www/html/` but in the instance there's no such `/var/www/html` path

[image: No such path as /var/www/html]

So, I've created these two folders in it

[image: SSH and folders]

and restarted the deployment

[image: Restart deployment]

but the it failed just like before.

How can I get the Deploy status to succeeded?

---

### Edit

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/error-codes.html), this error code shows **HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS**. So, I'm now reading:

- [Instance Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-health.html)
- [Troubleshoot instance issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ec2-instances.html)
- [Troubleshoot EC2/On-Premises Deployment Issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html)

Comment: What is your appspec file?

Comment: @Marcin i didn't have to create one. If it was created automatically anywhere in the process, I'm not able to locate it.

Comment: SSH in and ran `sudo find / -name "appspec"` but it didn't return anything

Comment: appspec.yml is a file you have to provide for codedeploy to work CodeDeploy AppSpec File reference - AWS CodeDeploy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html

Comment: @Marcin just added what might be relevant information based on the appspec.yml file. It references there a path that doesn't exist in the instance.

Comment: `CodeDeployGitHubDemo` is fine. I just deployed it using CodeDeploy in an attempt to test it. The repo is not the issue here in my view, though I used regular Amazon Linux 2 instance, not Lightsale. Maybe  you have to get back one step. Can you make it deploy with CodeDeploy only, without any pipelines? Get the code from the github, pack it into zip and deploy from S3 using codedeploy. This is what I did.

Comment: @Marcin feel free to write that as an answer and then I'll edit it to include more details of what was done. It particular, you can highlight the "you have to get back one step". It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments:

In an attempt to **reproduce** the issue, I deployed the application [CodeDeployGitHubDemo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html) used by the OP on my own Amazon Linux 2 instances with CodeDeploy. I could **verified** that the `CodeDeployGitHubDemo` and its `appspec.yml` files are correct and work as expected.

Since the OP is using CodePipline (CP), it was suggest to **go one step back** and focus on deployment using CodeDeploy (CD) only, without added complexity of using combination of CP + CD. This allows to focus only on CD issues and should simplify finding the root cause of the problems. Once standalone CD deployment works, the next step is to work on incorporating CP in the deployment process, knowing exactly how CD should be setup to work.

---

More specifically, this is what was done

1. In IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/

   1.1. Deleted one role (CodeDeployServiceRole).

   1.2. Created a service role.
2. In S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/

   2.1. Emptied and deleted one bucket (tiagocodedeploylightsailbucket).

   2.2. Created a new bucket in EU London (eu-west-2).
3. Back into the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/

   3.1. Deleted one policy (CodeDeployS3BucketPolicy).

   3.2. Created a new policy.
4. Stay in the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/

   4.1. Delete one user (LightSailCodeDeployUser)

   4.2. Created a new user (Note that it needs to have a different name or else would get [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168347/5675325)).
5. Navigate to the Lightsail home page at https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/

   5.1. Deleted previous instance (codedeploy).

   5.2. Created one new instance with Amazon Linux (Amazon_Linux_1) (Note that if used Amazon Linux 2 then would reach [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64143582/5675325)),

using the script

```
mkdir /etc/codedeploy-agent/

mkdir /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf

cat <<EOT >> /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeploy.onpremises.yml

---

aws_access_key_id: ACCESS_KEY

aws_secret_access_key: SECRET_KEY

iam_user_arn: arn:aws:iam::525221857828:user/GeneralUser

region: eu-west-2

EOT

wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/install

chmod +x ./install

sudo ./install auto
```

6. SSH in both instances

   6.1. Verify if codedeploy-agent is running (`sudo service codedeploy-agent status`)
7. In PowerShell with AWS CLI on your local machine

   7.1.

Run

```
aws deploy register-on-premises-instance --instance-name Amazon_Linux_1 --iam-user-arn arn:aws:iam::525221857828:user/GeneralUser --region eu-west-2
```

Then

```
aws deploy add-tags-to-on-premises-instances --instance-names Amazon_Linux_1 --tags Key=Name,Value=CodeDeployLightsailDemo --region eu-west-2
```

Then

```
aws deploy list-on-premises-instances --region eu-west-2
```

In the end, got as output

```
{
    "instanceNames": [
        "Amazon_Linux_1",
        "codedeploy"
    ]
}
```

8. Navigate to the CodeDeploy console at https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codedeploy/start?region=eu-west-2#

   8.1. Delete the application (CodeDeployLightsailDemo).

   8.2. Create a new application with a new deployment group (CodeDeployLightsailDemoDeploymentGroup).
9. Navigate to the CodePipeline console at https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codepipeline/start?region=eu-west-2

   9.1. Delete the pipeline (CodeDeployLightsailDemoPipeline).

   9.2. Create a new pipeline using "New service role".

[image: It worked]